# UIAccelerometer EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiaccelerometer

I am facing a bit strange problem with implementation of UIAccelerometer. 
I have a UITableViewController where I don't wanna use UIAccelerometer, but after pressing on of the rows I wanna activated one inside a UIViewController, everything is fine when I use simulator, but when I use device iPhone 3G to test it, I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS by pressing return button.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


     ShakeControl *percView = [[ShakeControl alloc] init];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:percView animated:YES];
     [percView release];


}
```

It works fine when I disable  [percView release];, but it does not sounds like solution for.
Any Idea would be appreciated.

Shake control implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1.0 / kUpdateFrequency];
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewDidUnload` method will get called only in specific case, such as memory warning. You have to remove the delegate in `dealloc` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try releasing it after you dismiss it, I'm not sure if pushViewController retains.

Comment: FWIW: pushViewController does add a retain

Comment: It certainly says it does, but perhaps on the device in this instance its not sending the retain message until after the release message has been sent. It shouldn't work this way of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could setting the environment variables NSZombiesEnabled & NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled with a value of 1.
This will prevent objects from really being deallocated, then you should get console logs indicating where the over-release is coming from.

You could use Run With Performance Tools -> Allocations once you know which object is being over-released and see every location where a retain/release was called to spot the imbalance.